# Which read concern is used for a MongoDB write operation?

Tags: mongodb

Some write operations not only write data but also read it.

An update can filter documents to be affected based on their state, and/or calculate a new field value depending on what the old one is.

This data that an update reads, is it majority committed, or is it just what there is on disk on the primary at the moment?

Does it depend on the write concern, maybe?

Or is there a way to somehow configure what the behaviour would be?

Comment: I am pretty sure that it's whatever the `PRIMARY` has at the moment. If that node were to check with the `SECONDARY` members to see which data had been replicated then the response could (probably would) be stale by the time it were ready to return to the client. AFAIK MongoDB is concerned about writing data locally on the `PRIMARY` only, this can (will) even be successfully done even if the requested write concern can't be satisfied. So I don't think there is any way to configure this behavior directly, but you adjust the concern knobs for (mostly other) operations depending on your needs

Comment: @user20042973, makes sense. This way the data an update bases on is the closest to the timestamp assigned to the update. Do you know by chance, if an update used some data that was rolled back afterwards, will the update be rolled back as well?

Comment: @user20042973, in the previous comment I wrote that taking just what the primary has makes sense, but then I thought again. It won't need to check with replicas, the primary should already have the majority committed version of the data in memory (where it's different from what's on disk). This in-memory structure on a primary should be updated very quickly every time a majority agrees on new data (though it can contain less recent data on replicas).

Comment: I don't understand the comments. Writes to MongoDB are well-ordered. Given chronological timestamps `t0` through `t5`, an update at `t5` that uses a value set at `t3` could not have the `t3` change undone without also undoing `t5`. Said another way, the db could roll back to `t4` (undoing the change at `t5`) or `t2`/earlier and undo both changes. No possibility of keeping the change at `t5` without also keeping `t3`. Also, the `PRIMARY` can, and usually does, contain changes that are not yet majority committed, though they typically become majority committed milliseconds later

Comment: @user20042973, if every rollback always rolls back a sequence of changes up to the last change on the primary, then indeed it seems logical to update based on what the primary has on disk. 

Is there a section in the docs to read about it in detail?